# Pandas drop duplicates only for main index

Tags: pandas

I have a multiindex and I want to perform drop_duplicates on a per level basis, I dont want to look at the entire dataframe but only if there is a duplicate with the same main index

Example:

```
entry,subentry,A,B

1 0 1.0 1.0
  1 1.0 1.0
  2 2.0 2.0

2 0 1.0 1.0
  1 2.0 2.0
  2 2.0 2.0
```

should return:

```
entry,subentry,A,B

1 0 1.0 1.0
  1 2.0 2.0

2 0 1.0 1.0
  1 2.0 2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) for filter out last row per `entry` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values('entry').duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df1)

                  A    B
entry subentry          
1     0         1.0  1.0
      1         1.0  1.0
2     0         1.0  1.0
      1         2.0  2.0
```

Or if need remove duplicates per first level and columns convert first level to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), for filter invert boolean mask by `~` and convert `Series` to numpy array, because indices of mask and original DataFrame not match:

```
df2 = df[~df.reset_index(level=0).duplicated(keep='last').to_numpy()]
print (df2)

                  A    B
entry subentry          
1     1         1.0  1.0
      2         2.0  2.0
2     0         1.0  1.0
      2         2.0  2.0
```

Or create helper column by first level of MultiIndex:

```
df2 = df[~df.assign(new=df.index.get_level_values('entry')).duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df2)

                  A    B
entry subentry          
1     1         1.0  1.0
      2         2.0  2.0
2     0         1.0  1.0
      2         2.0  2.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.reset_index(level=0))
          entry    A    B
subentry                 
0             1  1.0  1.0
1             1  1.0  1.0
2             1  2.0  2.0
0             2  1.0  1.0
1             2  2.0  2.0
2             2  2.0  2.0

print (~df.reset_index(level=0).duplicated(keep='last'))
0    False
1     True
2     True
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

---

```
print (df.assign(new=df.index.get_level_values('entry')))
                  A    B  new
entry subentry               
1     0         1.0  1.0    1
      1         1.0  1.0    1
      2         2.0  2.0    1
2     0         1.0  1.0    2
      1         2.0  2.0    2
      2         2.0  2.0    2
      
print (~df.assign(new=df.index.get_level_values('entry')).duplicated(keep='last'))
entry  subentry
1      0           False
       1            True
       2            True
2      0            True
       1           False
       2            True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) per group:

```
out = df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda d: d.drop_duplicates())
```

Or, a maybe more efficient variant using a temporary [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[~df.reset_index('entry').duplicated().values]
```

Output:

```
                  A    B
entry subentry          
1     0         1.0  1.0
      2         2.0  2.0
2     0         1.0  1.0
      1         2.0  2.0
```